# Wave-like and particle-like nature

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-optics, wave-particle-duality

My notes say

> Radiation emitted from any source moves **discontinuously** in form of small packets of energy. Each packet is called quantum.

Does this mean that when light travels, it is actually a particle jiggling up and down (and moving forward simultaneously, of course) creating a path that looks like a wave and is that why we call light to be travelling "like a wave"?

Possible duplicate of [What is Planck's quantum theory of radiation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/425722/)

But no satisfactory answer there, so asking again..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the relation between electromagnetic wave and photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90646/)